# Calculate weighted average purchase price (trades table with reset)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to calculate the weighted average price for stocks using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.
The difference with what I'm asking is that when all stocks have been sold the weighted price should be reset

**Issue**
*NewPrice* is incorrect in the following trades table

[image]

**Expected Output**

```
Row   NewPrice
1      186.4000
2      186.4000
3      183.0800
4      183.0800
5      183.0800
6      183.0800
7      183.0800
8      183.0800
7      183.0800
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  *,   
                        PriceRunningTotalFinal = 
                        SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN QuantityRunningTotal = 0 THEN -1 * PriceRunningTotal
                                WHEN Units < 0 THEN 0 ELSE PurchasePrice * Units END) OVER 
                        (
                        PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
                        ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                        ),   


                        CASE WHEN Results1.QuantityRunningTotal <= 0 then 0
                        else 
                        SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN QuantityRunningTotal <= 0 THEN -1 * PriceRunningTotal
                                WHEN Units < 0 THEN 0 ELSE PurchasePrice * Units END) OVER 
                        (
                        PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
                        ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                        )   / Results1.QuantityRunningTotal 
                        end as NewPrice
                    FROM 
                        (
                        SELECT Id, UserCompetitionId, StockId, Type,  Units, PurchasePrice, CreatedOn,
                          QuantityRunningTotal = SUM(Units) OVER 
                          (
                            PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
                            ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                          ),  
                          PriceRunningTotal = SUM(CASE WHEN Units <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE PurchasePrice * Units END) OVER 
                          (
                            PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
                            ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                          ) 

                          FROM Trade
                        ) AS Results1
                        WHERE UserCompetitionId =@UserCompetitionId AND StockId = 122
```

The problem I'm having is with the newPrice.
From **Row 4** onwards the price should be **183.08000**

This is because all previous stocks have been sold (QuantityRunningTotal is 0). Therefore the weighted purchase price calculation needs to start again and not take into account the previous rows

**UPDATE**
Looking at **Andrei Odegov** answer, the solution works. But one thing I failed to mention is that I would like to get the adjusted weighted prices for each row 
As can be seen in this screenshot:
[image]

**Weighted average price**
I tried to get the average price, it sort of works but I'm not sure it's the right way to go about it?

```
DECLARE @Trade TABLE(
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  UserCompetitionId INT DEFAULT(92170),
  StockId INT DEFAULT(122),
  Type INT,
  Units INT,
  PurchasePrice NUMERIC(8, 4)
);

INSERT @Trade(Type, Units, PurchasePrice)
  VALUES (10, 42, 186.4),
         (20, -42, 183.08),
         (10, 40, 183.08),
         (20, -5, 183.92),
         (20, -1, 181.68),
         (20, -1, 181.68),
         (20, -1, 181.68),         
         (20, 17, 181.68),
         (20, -10, 181.68);

WITH
  A AS(
    SELECT
      *,
      QuantityRunningTotal = SUM(Units) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      )
    FROM @Trade
  ),
  B AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      Grp = SUM(IIF(QuantityRunningTotal - Units <= 0, 1, 0)) OVER
            (
              PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
              ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
            )
    FROM A
  )


  SELECT *, TotalAmount / Qty
  FROM (

    SELECT
      *,
      Units * PurchasePrice AS PurchaseAmount,
      NewPrice = FIRST_VALUE(PurchasePrice) OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId, Grp
        ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),
      row_number() over (partition by UserCompetitionId, StockId order by Id desc) as Seq,
       TotalAmount = SUM(CASE WHEN Units < 0 THEN 0 ELSe Units * PurchasePrice END) OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId, Grp
        ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),
       Qty = SUM(CASE WHEN Units < 0 THEN 0 ELSe Units  END) OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId, Grp
        ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      )
    FROM B
    )AS Result
WHERE Result.Seq = 1 AND QuantityRunningTotal > 0
ORDER BY StockId;
```

**UPDATE2 (Gets the overall purchase price $50.65)**

```
DECLARE @Trade TABLE(
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  UserCompetitionId INT DEFAULT(92170),
  StockId INT DEFAULT(122),
  Units INT,
  PurchasePrice NUMERIC(8, 4)
);

INSERT @Trade(Units, PurchasePrice)
VALUES (100, 97.8774),
       (200, 97.89),
       (-300, 97.8858),
       (600, 48.9429),
       (100, 60.9),
       (-600, 60.395);

WITH
  A AS(
    SELECT
      *,
      Amount = SUM(IIF(Units > 0, Units * PurchasePrice, 0)) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),
      Qty = SUM(IIF(Units > 0, Units, 0)) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),
      Qty2 = SUM(Units) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),

      TotalAmount = SUM(Units * PurchasePrice) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      )
     FROM @Trade            
  )
SELECT
  Units AS Amount,
  CAST(PurchasePrice AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS [Purchase Price],
  CAST(ABS(Units * PurchasePrice) AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [Purchase Amount],
  CAST(Amount / Qty AS NUMERIC(6, 2)) AS "Adjusted Purchase Price",
  Qty2,
  TotalAmount,
  IIF(Qty2 = 0, 0,TotalAmount/ Qty2) AS Average
FROM A
ORDER BY Id;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: At row 4, The positive values of units exceed the negatives, and the balance is not zero - so what does 'all stocks are sold' mean?  Very hard to understand what it means.

Comment: @cato Basically if you start from the top, bought 42 units, then sold 42, then bought 40, then sold 5 onwards ... so by row 4 you have 35 units as indicated by QuantityRunningTotal. By the end of it you only have 2 units of that stock

Comment: so we only have 2 left, but 2 is not nothing, so has all the stock been sold?  At row 4 you have 35, why would that indicate 'all sold'?

Comment: @Cato I mean at row 2 they would of been all sold, at Row 3 I have bought a new lot

Comment: You maybe need to make a workrd example, or maybe someone else knows more about it - sorry I can't really help at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result using the [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) function.

```
WITH
  A AS(
    SELECT
      *,
      QuantityRunningTotal = SUM(Units) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      )
    FROM @Trade
  ),
  B AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      Grp = SUM(IIF(QuantityRunningTotal - Units <= 0, 1, 0)) OVER
            (
              PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
              ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
            )
    FROM A
  )
SELECT
  *,
  NewPrice = FIRST_VALUE(PurchasePrice) OVER
  (
    PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId, Grp
    ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  )
FROM B
ORDER BY Id;
```

**Output:**

```
+----+-------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----+----------+
| Id | UserCompetitionId | StockId | Type | Units | PurchasePrice | QuantityRunningTotal | Grp | NewPrice |
+----+-------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----+----------+
|  1 |             92170 |     122 |   10 |    42 | 186,4000      |                   42 |   1 | 186,4000 |
|  2 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |   -42 | 183,0800      |                    0 |   1 | 186,4000 |
|  3 |             92170 |     122 |   10 |    40 | 183,0800      |                   40 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  4 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    -5 | 183,9200      |                   35 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  5 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    -1 | 181,6800      |                   34 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  6 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    -1 | 181,6800      |                   33 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  7 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    -1 | 181,6800      |                   32 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  8 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    -2 | 181,6800      |                   30 |   2 | 183,0800 |
|  9 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |   -30 | 181,6800      |                    0 |   2 | 183,0800 |
| 10 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |    17 | 181,6800      |                   17 |   3 | 181,6800 |
| 11 |             92170 |     122 |   20 |   -10 | 181,6800      |                    7 |   3 | 181,6800 |
+----+-------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----+----------+
```

**Demo:**
https://rextester.com/IMN29774.

**Update:**
The figures of this your screenshot[image] can be obtained using the following query:

```
DECLARE @Trade TABLE(
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  UserCompetitionId INT DEFAULT(92170),
  StockId INT DEFAULT(122),
  Units INT,
  PurchasePrice NUMERIC(8, 4)
);

INSERT @Trade(Units, PurchasePrice)
VALUES (100, 97.8774),
       (200, 97.89),
       (-300, 97.8858),
       (600, 48.9429),
       (100, 60.9),
       (-600, 60.395);

WITH
  A AS(
    SELECT
      *,
      Amount = SUM(IIF(Units > 0, Units * PurchasePrice, 0)) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      ),
      Qty = SUM(IIF(Units > 0, Units, 0)) OVER
      (
       PARTITION BY UserCompetitionId, StockId
       ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
      )
    FROM @Trade
  )
SELECT
  Units AS Amount,
  CAST(PurchasePrice AS NUMERIC(6,2)) AS [Purchase Price],
  CAST(ABS(Units * PurchasePrice) AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS [Purchase Amount],
  CAST(Amount / Qty AS NUMERIC(6, 2)) AS "Adjusted Purchase Price"
FROM A
ORDER BY Id;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| Amount |Purchase Price|Purchase Amount|Adjusted Purchase Price|
+--------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|    100 | 97,88        | 9787,74       | 97,88                 |
|    200 | 97,89        | 19578,00      | 97,89                 |
|   -300 | 97,89        | 29365,74      | 97,89                 |
|    600 | 48,94        | 29365,74      | 65,26                 |
|    100 | 60,90        | 6090,00       | 64,82                 |
|   -600 | 60,40        | 36237,00      | 64,82                 |
+--------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, much appreciated, exactly what I was after. 
I guess the trick was to use FIRST_VALUE CTE with Group Number

Comment: I have updated the question slightly to try to work out how to get the Adjusted New Price. In your example if you take off Row 8 & 9. You will find that you would have 2 units @ 183.08 and 17 units @ 181.68, therefore the NewPrice would read 181.99. When I tried your sample and removed those rows, the new price didn't reflect that?

Comment: Thank you so much Andrei, once again exactly what I was after and it works well much appreciated. You've helped me understand window functions a little better

Comment: One thing I did notice is in the screenshot there is an overall value of  $50.65. I guess I need to combine both your queries to get that value. I'll have a go at it

Comment: Please see **UPDATE2** in my question for the query to help get get the $50.65. It works but not sure if it's optimal