# Stocks wallet with running values and average buying prices with reset

Tags: sql-server, accounting

I was working in a personal investments worksheet and thinking on the smallest amount of information required to make it useful and to be able to compute each asset balance and current average value.

I saw several examples, most of them relying on debit and credit columns, or using a single line to add the buy/sell price; the first case would require at least two row to express where the money came/went to; the second one makes hard to express partial sells (like buying 100 stocks, selling 50 and later buying 50 more; what is the current position and average buying value?)

With that in mind, I came with something like [I described here](https://superuser.com/questions/1579693/using-excel-to-summarize-credit-and-debit-category-columns-and-a-single-value-co?noredirect=1#comment2406140_1579693)

Consider the following dataset:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
VALUES  (1, '2020-08-01', 'MBIT', 'POCKET', 'MONEY', 100.00, 100.00, 'Added $100 from my pocket into MBIT broker'),
        (2, '2020-08-02', 'MBIT', 'MONEY' , 'XPTO' ,   0.50, 100.00, 'Bought 0.50 XPTO for $100 (thus rate=200)'),
        (3, '2020-08-03', 'MBIT', 'XPTO'  , 'MONEY',   0.50, 125.00, 'Sold   0.50 XPTO for $125 (thus rate=250, $25 profit)'),
        (4, '2020-08-04', 'MBIT', 'MONEY' , 'XPTO' ,   0.35,  85.00, 'Bought 0.35 XPTO for $85  (thus rate=~242.85)'),
        (5, '2020-08-05', 'MBIT', 'MONEY' , 'WXYZ' ,   1.75,  20.00, 'Bought 1.75 WXYZ for $20 (rate~=11.43)'),
        (6, '2020-08-06', 'MBIT', 'MONEY' , 'WXYZ' ,   1.85,  15.00, 'Bought 1.85 WXYZ for $15 (new total = 3.6 for $35, rate~=9.72)'))
        Entries([Order#], Date, Broker,  Debit, Credit, Quantity, Value, Description)
```

I would like to calculate the current averages and balance for each broker/asset; how to do that?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145380/calculate-weighted-average-purchase-price-trades-table-with-reset

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be identify the assets that should be evaluated as money (ie. having a fixed rate of 1) and store the current quotes for other assets:

```
WITH    Coins   AS
(       SELECT  *
        FROM    (
        VALUES  ('POCKET', 1,   1.00),  -- Pocket and money always have $1 price
                ('MONEY' , 1,   1.00),  -- Pocket and money always have $1 price
                ('XPTO'  , 0, 200.00),  -- Current rate for this asset
                ('WXYZ'  , 0,   8.50))
                Entries(Name, IsMoney, [Current])
)
```

Then we need to split each line from the given dataset (named `RawData`), so we can have a row for the credit part, and another row for the debit. We also need to compute the rate for each asset that isn't money:

```
,       Accounting  AS
(       SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date, Order#, Quantity) Sequence,
                [Order#], Date, Broker, Account, IsMoney, Description,
                CASE WHEN Coins.IsMoney = 1 THEN Value ELSE Quantity END Quantity, Value /
                CASE WHEN Coins.IsMoney = 1 THEN Value ELSE Quantity END Rate
        FROM    (   SELECT  [Order#], Date, Broker, Debit  AS Account,
                            -Quantity Quantity, -Value Value, Description
                    FROM    RawData
                    UNION   ALL
                    SELECT  [Order#], Date, Broker, Credit AS Account,
                            +Quantity Quantity, +Value Value, Description
                    FROM    RawData
                )   Accounting
        LEFT
        JOIN    Coins
            ON  Coins.Name = Accounting.Account
)
```

Pretty straightforward; so far we got this:
[image]

On the [SuperUser question comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1579693/using-excel-to-summarize-credit-and-debit-category-columns-and-a-single-value-co?noredirect=1#comment2406140_1579693), I figured out that would be tricky to calculate the average prices, specially considering I would need to ignore closed positions.

As the operation that sells asset balance isn't directly tied to the one/multiple that buys it, I was dead in the water.

The turning point was when I realized I don't need to match those: all I need is to find out when the balance was zeroed, and to use only the latest "version" of it.

So I turned to the windowed functions; the challenge here was to identify when the balance was reseted. Some googling took me to a [T-SQL Feature Request: Add RESET WHEN Clause to Reset Window Partition](https://www.itprotoday.com/programming-languages/t-sql-feature-request-add-reset-when-clause-reset-window-partition) where the author brilliantly describes how the request feature would help to make simpler queries and gives hints on how to overcome them while the Microsoft folks to dot approve it.

```
,   Balance AS
(   SELECT  *,
            MAX(BalanceVersion) OVER (PARTITION BY Broker, Account) LatestVersion
    FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                SUM(BalanceReset) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Broker, Account
                    ORDER BY Sequence)  BalanceVersion
                FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                                    CASE    WHEN    LAG(Total) OVER (
                                                        PARTITION BY Broker, Account
                                                        ORDER BY Sequence) = 0
                                            THEN    1
                                            ELSE    0
                                    END     BalanceReset
                            FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                                                SUM (Quantity) OVER (
                                                    PARTITION BY Broker, Account
                                                    ORDER BY Sequence) AS Total
                                        FROM    Accounting
                                    )   Account
                        )   Reset
            )   Versions
)
```

Taking this thing apart:

- Lets first calculate the running total for each asset (`Account` subselect)
- Them we identify when the balance goes zero, using the [`LAG` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (`Reset` subselect)
- Lets compute a new running total, now using the reset identifiers to group the balances (`Versions` subselect)
- The last step would be to identify what is the latest version for each broker/asset group

[image: Balance resultset]

By identifying the "data islands" we're back in the game!

Lets now calculate the correct average and the final balance for the open positions:

```
,   Final AS
(   SELECT  Broker, Account,
            SUM(Quantity) Quantity,
            SUM(CASE WHEN IsMoney = 1 THEN 1.000 ELSE [Rate] * Quantity  END) /
            SUM(CASE WHEN IsMoney = 1 THEN 1.000 ELSE Quantity  END) Rate
    FROM    Balance
    WHERE   BalanceVersion = LatestVersion
    GROUP
        BY  Broker, Account
)
```

[image: Final resultset]

All the windowed function madness was required to build the right `XPTO` balance; for that calculation, we must not use the first buy/sell operations, as it zeroed the position and we need to start over for having the right average buying price.

The rest of the query is just a matter of putting the current asset prices and the computed balance and average prices together:

```
SELECT  Final.Broker,
        Final.Account,
        Final.Quantity,
        Final.Rate  [Original],
         Coins.[Current]    [Current],
        (Coins.[Current] / Final.Rate)-1 [%],
        (Coins.[Current] * Final.Quantity) [Value]
FROM    Final
LEFT
JOIN    Coins
    ON  Coins.Name = Final.Account
ORDER
    BY  Final.Broker,
        Final.Account
```

The result is this:
[image: Final report]

Looking at the data we can see:

- how much we invested in that broker (`POCKET` value)
- how much money we have sitting idle in the broker (`MONEY` value)
- the balance of `WXYZ`

  - we first bought 1.75 WXYZ for $20 (rate: 20/1.75 ~=11.43)
  - then we bought more 1.85 WXYZ for $15 (rate: 15/1.85 ~=8.10)
  - therefor the right average price is (20+15)/(1.75+1.85) ~= 9.72
- the balance of `XPTO`

  - if we consider all operations, we'll come with an average value of 171.43
  - that is wrong because if we bought some asset quantity and sold all asset, those prices shouldn't affect new buying prices
  - so, the right average value for this asset is ~242.85

**Conclusion**: In this hypothetical scenario:

- We invested $100;
- Made $25 profit;
- Bought some XPTO
- Bought some WXYZ
- WXYZ market price decreased and we bought some more
- XPTO is 12.57% down since we bought it for the last time
- WXYZ is 17.65% down, considering the average price for both previous acquisitions
- If we sum all values from the last column, we can see we still have a $5.60 profit